# Extracting strings out of a String response

Tags: android, json, string, substring

I have following String response. Out of which I want to extract MAC ID & other fields like Version, Type, devIP etc.

```
Response ={ 
"Version" : “1.10", 
"Type" :"'xyzTYPE", 
"MaCID" :"ABCD1F2G3900", 
"devIP" : "'192.168.1.100", 
"Signal": "-66", 
"AreaName" :"'power", 
"SubType" :"wifidev", 
"'BuiIdTime" : "11:50:47", 
"'BuiIdDate": "'Nov 2 2018" 
}
```

Though I have implemented it in this way.

`String macID = result.substring(result.indexOf("MaCID")+11,result.indexOf("devIP")-4);`

I want to know if there is another sophisticated manner to do the same.

Comment: is your `Response` is JSON ?

Comment: The best way is to create class for the response and deserialize the response into object format.

Comment: Sure there is. Your method is pretty fragile. Have a look at a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response looks like JSON,
so for json response in result;

```
 JSONObject lsubObject= new JSONObject(result);
    String MaCID =lsubObject.getString("MaCID");
```